# Write URL to NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

How can I write a URL to a NFC tag so that the link automatically opens on read?

Currently, I am using the following intent:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.ReadTagActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_readtag"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/com.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>          
  </activity>
```

If the write operation enters the URL www.google.com,
the read will only display the string. I would like the URL 
to open in a browser instead. How can I fix this?

Comment: "Currently, I am using the following intent" -- that has nothing to do with writing to NFC tags. "If the write operation" -- consider posting the source code for that "write operation", specifically how you are constructing your `NdefRecord`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you writing a correct NDEF Record with the URL in the NDEF Message?

Such as using the helper method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#createUri%28android.net.Uri%29

If your NDEF Record is just plain text, it will be read as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

```
NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
Intent intent = getIntent();       
Tag mytag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
Uri uri =Uri.parse("Your Url");
NdefRecord recordNFC =NdefRecord.createUri(uri);
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(recordNFC ); 
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
ndef.connect();
ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
ndef.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to write Link in the NFC tag.

```
ndef.connect();
NdefRecord mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(linkPrefix + pageLink);
ndef.writeNdefMessage(new NdefMessage(mimeRecord));
ndef.close();
```

you can write `below` link prefix into **linkPrefix** field

```
"http://www."
"https://www."
"ftps://"
"sftp://"
"smb://"
"nfs://"
"ftp://"
"dav://"
"file://"
```

and write page link into **pageLink** field

- google.com
- stackoverflow.com , etx